# How to change the items of a navigation drawer after login

Tags: android

i am developping an android app that contain a navigation drawer in which i have 4 items : Home , Connection , Contact , About us 
When i click on Connection it opens a login fragment in which contains button to login 
After clicking on login i wanna change the visibity on connection item to false and logout to true
Please help me

Comment: What have you done ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make following changes after the login is done......

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    //all other stuff of app here
    ...
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // for getting menu from navigationView
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    // finding menuItem that you want to change
    MenuItem nav_connection = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_connection);

    // set new title to the MenuItem"change name from connection to logout"
    nav_connection.setTitle("Logout");


    // add NavigationItemSelectedListener to check the navigation clicks
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Hope this will help you,
works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this feature by implementing following logic. Initialize the following declaration :

```
    private NavigationView navigationView; 
    private boolean isAfterLogin;
```

Initialize the navigationView

```
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Let us assume, after your successful login, you control goes back to activity having Navigation view. Implement a shared pref or some boolean variable to check if the activity is opened after successful login.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isAfterLogin =  checkForLogin(); // create this method to check your login status to avoid compilation error.
    if(isAfterLogin){

     Menu navigationMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
     navigationMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_connection).setVisible(false);
     navigationMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setVisible(true);

}
```

The value R.id.nav_connection is the id defined in navigation drawer menu.

Hope it solves the problem. Revert if you face any issue.

Comment: But how can i know the id of my navigation drawer menu? Sorry but im debutant

Comment: You check the menu folder inside res > menu > menu_navigation.xml  ( plz note menu_navigation.xml  is for reference ). The actual name may vary. If the menu items didn't have an id, assign id to each menu element.

Comment: This is my LoginFragment

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see your login fragment. It would be great if you can put content of your activity, fragment and its corresponding layout and menu.xml